# Visitor pattern, Extensible visitor for custom implementation

Tags: c#, design-patterns, visitor-pattern

I'm writing my own expression tree system, just for fun, but I have a few doubts about my code.
My goal here is to create an abstract layer of expressions, and allow different *"languages"* to extend it.

For example, those are my base components :

```cs
//Base expression class for all expressions in every domain
public abstract class Expression
{
    public void Accept(Visitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}

//Base left-right (binary) expression class for all binary expressions in every domain
public abstract class BinaryExpression : Expression
{
    protected BinaryExpression(Expression left,Expression right)
    {
        Left = left;
        Right = right;
    }

    public Expression Left { get; }
    public Expression Right { get; }
}

//Base assignment expression (x <= y) class for all assignment expressions in every domain
public abstract class AssignmentExpression : BinaryExpression
{
    protected AssignmentExpression(Expression destination,Expression source)
        : base(destination,source)
    {
        Destination = destination;
        Source = source;
    }
    
    public Expression Destination { get; }
    public Expression Source { get; }
}

//The visitor class who can visit expressions
public abstract class Visitor
{
    public abstract void Visit(Expression expression);
}
```

And I have two languages using the definitions above.
Language A :

```cs
//The LangA visitor
public class LangAVisitor : Visitor
{
    public void Visit(LangAMoveExpression expression)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("LangAMoveExpression");
    }
    
    public override void Visit(Expression expression)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("LangAExpression");
        Visit((dynamic)expression);
    }
}

//Language A assignment expression (known for this language as move)
public class LangAMoveExpression : AssignmentExpression
{
    public LangAMoveExpression(Expression destination,Expression source)
        : base(destination,source)
    {
    
    }
}

//Just an empty expression
public class LangAEmptyExpression : Expression
{
    
}
```

And Language B :

```cs
//The LangB visitor
public class LangBVisitor : Visitor
{
    public void Visit(LangBStoreExpression expression)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("LangBStoreExpression");
    }
    
    public override void Visit(Expression expression)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("LangBExpression");
        Visit((dynamic)expression);
    }
}

//Language B assignment expression (known for this language as store)
public class LangBStoreExpression : AssignmentExpression
{
    public LangBStoreExpression(Expression destination,Expression source)
        : base(destination,source)
    {
    
    }
}

//Just an empty expression
public class LangBEmptyExpression : Expression
{
    
}
```

Execution Example :

```cs
void Main()
{
    Execute(new LangAVisitor(),new LangAMoveExpression(new LangAEmptyExpression(),new LangAEmptyExpression()));
    Execute(new LangBVisitor(),new LangBStoreExpression(new LangBEmptyExpression(),new LangBEmptyExpression()));
}

void Execute(Visitor visitor,params Expression[] expressions)
{
    foreach(var expression in expressions)
    {
        expression.Accept(visitor);
    }
}
```

1. I am able to get the desired output I want thanks to the code supplied, but I really don't like the `dynamic` casting approach, is there any way I can implement this better?

   Also, i need to keep the executing as generic as possible.
2. Many doubts came to me when placing the `public void Accept(Visitor visitor)` in the base `Expression` class, should it even be there?
3. How extensible is this code ?
   Is it well architecture for any upcoming extensions ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: With the traditional Visitor pattern, the Expression types are not very extensible (visitor is more suitable when you have a fixed set of expressions), but you can easily add different languages (you just create another Visitor derivative). I've written a bit about this in an [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/412392/275536) to a different question, it will help you understand what Visitor is actually about. 1/2

Comment: Traditionally, the Visitor base class would actually have a separate Visit method for each direct child of Expression - these would be differentiated either by name, or by the type signature (relying on overload resolution) - see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). The whole thing with `dynamic` here doesn't seem to really solve anything (at first glance), it just adds unnecessary complexity while appearing helpful. It has the same constraint - if you add a new type of Expression, you'd still need to update all the Language classes. 2/2

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking, in Visitor pattern _**Visitor** lets you define a new operation without changing the classes of the elements on which it operates_ or in another words _Represents an operation to be performed on elements of an object structure_ - in your implementation, I assume an `Expression` is an operation which is "visiting" an object("host").

Comment: @Fabio - "I assume an Expression is an operation" - I'm not sure, but I think Expression is just used to represent an abstract syntax tree (so, not an executable operation, just data representing some code/expression, like something a compiler would produce). If so, then it fits the role of a traversable tree of elements that visitors act upon, and Visitor derivatives like OP's "languages" could actually be operations like "interpret". One reason why I suspect this is the case is because that particular example is often used (most notably, the Go4 book uses an AST to motivate the pattern).